# Using Chromium Edge WebView2 on vs2015 & 32 bit application (limitation i have)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, chromium, 32bit-64bit, webview2

Does anyone succeed to works with WebView2 and chromium Edge on vs 2015 - 32-bit application?

I try the WPF .Net 4.8 sample at vs2015 and its works only at 64 bit,
I try also the c++ on vs2015 but I didn't succeed to make it works :-(

I try the latest release and pre-release.(v0.9.628)

if someone succeded and can share a snippet code, I will be happy :-)

Thanks
Oren

Comment: Do you use 'x86' as cpu or 'anycpu' with 'prefer 32 bit' ? You should use 'x86'.

Comment: On 'x86' and on 'AnyCpu with prefer 32 bit' I got the same Exception  :
'System.BadImageFormatException'
{" is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)"}

When calling to function : webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async.
only when compiling vs2015 with anyCpu (without prefer 32 bit) the project works well 
Thanks
Oren